# Moving ruby and rubygems into a custom path

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a local ruby interpreter created a third party which is  installed under `/usr/lib/projectA/ruby/bin/ruby`

Now, I want to copy the whole folder strcuture into another folder with the same structure: `/usr/lib/projectB/ruby/bin/ruby`

After I copied the files, and call the copied ruby, e.g.

```
# /usr/lib/projectB/ruby/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.9.x
```

Seems to be working, however, when I run

```
# /usr/lib/projectB/ruby/bin/ruby -e 'puts 1'
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

Seems it can't find the rubygems, so I add the path

```
# /usr/lib/projectB/ruby/bin/ruby -e 'puts 1' -I '/usr/lib/projectB/ruby/lib/'
/usr/lib/projectB/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:31:in `require': cannot load such file -- rbconfig (LoadError)
```

Now, another files cannot be loaded, so I assume more to come..

So

1. What is the correct method to set the new **rubygems** base path for my new ruby?
2. Why even calling `puts 1` will invoke the rubygems?

p.s. I can't use rvm or similar approach as we need to deploy the whole zip package with the ruby to our user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RVM and set the path in your `.rvmrc`  file via `rvm_path` parameter.
Also double check your `~/.bashrc`  or `~/.bash_profile` if the paths are OK.

Other option is to play with `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for ruby and use `$GEM_PATH` which provides the locations (there may be several) where gems can be found.
You probably will need to play with Ruby's environmental variables:

```
RUBYOPT     Additional command-line options to Ruby; examined after real command-line options are parsed ($SAFE must be 0).
RUBYLIB     Additional search path for Ruby programs ($SAFE must be 0).
RUBYPATH    With -S option, search path for Ruby programs (defaults to PATH).
RUBYSHELL   Shell to use when spawning a process; if not set, will also check SHELL or COMSPEC.
DLN_LIBRARY_PATH    Search path for dynamically loaded modules.
RUBYLIB_PREFIX  (Windows only) Mangle the RUBYLIB search path by adding this prefix to each component.
```

from [here](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/rubyworld.html).